# app works on simulator but not on iPhone

Tags: ios5

I have developed and iPhone app and it seems to work fine on the simulator 5.0. However, when I tried to test it on the real device, an iphone w/ ios 5, it's not working.
The app launched but all I see was a black screen.

Here's the crash log I found in the Device Log
Sorry I am pretty new to this.. I am not sure if these are symbolicated. (seems like they are?)

> ```
> Incident Identifier: B2601015-4CBF-478D-B9C3-2D2B4BEED892
> CrashReporter Key:   9c71d7c2ed64b2862a0a6d90e3d4ce839868a03c
> Hardware Model:      iPhone4,1
> Process:         memoryChallenger [21037]
> Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/C0981716-8CDF-4816-8E94- 261CD8F164FD/memoryChallenger.app/memoryChallenger
> Identifier:      memoryChallenger
> Version:         ??? (???)
> Code Type:       ARM (Native)
> Parent Process:  launchd [1]
>
> Date/Time:       2012-01-30 21:54:18.753 -0800
> OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.0.1 (9A405)
> Report Version:  104
>
> Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
> Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
> Crashed Thread:  0
>
> Last Exception Backtrace:
> 0   CoreFoundation                    0x37ecb8bf __exceptionPreprocess + 163
> 1   libobjc.A.dylib                   0x319b11e5 objc_exception_throw + 33
> 2   CoreFoundation                    0x37ecb7b9 +[NSException raise:format:] + 1
> 3   CoreFoundation                    0x37ecb7db +[NSException raise:format:] + 35
> 4   UIKit                             0x354f7747 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1567
> 5   UIKit                             0x354f8bb9 -[NSBundle(UINSBundleAdditions) loadNibNamed:owner:options:] + 137
> 6   UIKit                             0x35431a45 -[UIApplication _loadMainNibFileNamed:bundle:] + 37
> 7   UIKit                             0x352bb227 -[UIApplication _loadMainInterfaceFile] + 223
> 8   UIKit                             0x352b5313 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 227
> 9   UIKit                             0x35283921 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1017
> 10  UIKit                             0x352833bf -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 55
> 11  UIKit                             0x35282d2d _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 5809
> 12  GraphicsServices                  0x379a0df3 PurpleEventCallback + 883
> 13  CoreFoundation                    0x37e9f553 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 39
> 14  CoreFoundation                    0x37e9f4f5 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 141
> 15  CoreFoundation                    0x37e9e343 __CFRunLoopRun + 1371
> 16  CoreFoundation                    0x37e214dd CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 301
> 17  CoreFoundation                    0x37e213a5 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105
> 18  UIKit                             0x352b4457 -[UIApplication _run] + 551
> 19  UIKit                             0x352b1743 UIApplicationMain + 1091
> 20  memoryChallenger                  0x000050d9 main (main.m:14)
> 21  memoryChallenger                  0x000027ec start + 40
>
>
> Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
> Thread 0 Crashed:
> 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x3376532c __pthread_kill + 8
> 1   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x36331f54 pthread_kill + 48
> 2   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x3632afe4 abort + 88
> 3   libc++abi.dylib                   0x37e10f64 abort_message + 40
> 4   libc++abi.dylib                   0x37e0e346 _ZL17default_terminatev + 18
> 5   libobjc.A.dylib                   0x319b12dc _objc_terminate + 140
> 6   libc++abi.dylib                   0x37e0e3be _ZL19safe_handler_callerPFvvE + 70
> 7   libc++abi.dylib                   0x37e0e44a std::terminate() + 14
> 8   libc++abi.dylib                   0x37e0f81e __cxa_rethrow + 82
> 9   libobjc.A.dylib                   0x319b122e objc_exception_rethrow + 6
> 10  CoreFoundation                    0x37e2153e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 398
> 11  CoreFoundation                    0x37e2139e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
> 12  UIKit                             0x352b4450 -[UIApplication _run] + 544
> 13  UIKit                             0x352b173c UIApplicationMain + 1084
> 14  memoryChallenger                  0x000050d2 main (main.m:14)
> 15  memoryChallenger                  0x000027e4 start + 32
>
> Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
> Thread 1:
> 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x337553b4 kevent + 24
> 1   libdispatch.dylib                 0x37b89f74 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 708
> 2   libdispatch.dylib                 0x37b89c92 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 30
>
> Thread 2:
> 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x33765cd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
> 1   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x362ee30a _pthread_wqthread + 610
> 2   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x362ee09c start_wqthread + 0
>
> Thread 3:
> 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x33765cd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
> 1   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x362ee30a _pthread_wqthread + 610
> 2   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x362ee09c start_wqthread + 0
>
> Thread 4 name:  WebThread
> Thread 4:
> 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x33755010 mach_msg_trap + 20
> 1   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x33755206 mach_msg + 50
> 2   CoreFoundation                    0x37e9f41c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 120
> 3   CoreFoundation                    0x37e9e154 __CFRunLoopRun + 876
> 4   CoreFoundation                    0x37e214d6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
> 5   CoreFoundation                    0x37e2139e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
> 6   WebCore                           0x326f2128 _ZL12RunWebThreadPv + 396
> 7   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x362f3c16 _pthread_start + 314
> 8   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x362f3ad0 thread_start + 0
>
> Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
>     r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x00000000
>     r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x3f31dce8      r6: 0x00000002      r7: 0x2fdff864
>     r8: 0x3f14edec    r9: 0x00000000     r10: 0x00188cc0     r11: 0x00185b40
>     ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x2fdff858      lr: 0x36331f5b      pc: 0x3376532c
>   cpsr: 0x00000010
> ```

it seems like this line here is what I am looking for..

> ```
> 20  memoryChallenger                  0x000050d9 main (main.m:14)
> ```

and it's this line in main:

> ```
> int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
> ```

But it's not getting me anywhere..

Can someone please guide me to the right direction?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

From this line,

```
-[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1567
```

it looks like your application's XIB file wasn't copied over properly to device.
Do a clean install.

Answer (score 1):

For my case, it is due to the XIB file not found for iOS 5 (even though it's copied into the app bundle).

It is due to using Base Internationalization, which is only supported in iOS 6.

Strangely, running on Simulator with iOS 5 will work. That got to be a bug.

I have detailed my experience after releasing my app with this dumb startup crash: http://samwize.com/2012/11/22/warning-do-not-use-base-internationalization-in-ios-5/

Comment: Wow, same here. This is just insane. Why doesn't Xcode warn when I add Base Internationalization but my deployment target is 5.1?

Answer (score 0):

In IB, xib's **Target Membership** -> current target is **not checked**

Just another scenario when this occurs.